# Head and shoulders trading strategy

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to encode the Head and shoulders trading strategy into my python code.

Based on the relative extrema of the last five indexes.

my first index should be a maximum. the third index > the first index. the third index should also be greater than the fifth index.

indexes 1 and 5 should be within 1.5% of their average
and indexes 2 and 4 should be within 1.5% of their average.

here is my code. anyone is free to take a look at my problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from HarmonicFunctions import *
from tqdm import tqdm
from TraditionalFunctions import *
# Import our historical data

data = pd.read_csv('GBPJPY.csv')

data.columns = ['Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']

data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)

data = data[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]

price = data.close.copy()

# Find Peaks

err_allowed = 5.0/100

XA = current_pat[1] - current_pat[0]
AB = current_pat[2] - current_pat[1]
BC = current_pat[3] - current_pat[2]
CD = current_pat[4] - current_pat[3]

moves = [XA,AB,BC,CD]

def peak_detect(price,order=10):

    max_idx = list(argrelextrema(price, np.greater, order=order)[0])
    min_idx = list(argrelextrema(price, np.less, order=order)[0])

    idx = max_idx + min_idx + [len(price)-1]

    idx.sort()

    current_idx = idx[-5:]

    start = min(current_idx)
    end = max(current_idx)

    current_pat = price[current_idx]

    return current_idx,current_pat,start,end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is your question?

Comment: Im having a brain fart and having a hard time formatting that strategy into code. I was hoping someone would be able to help.

Comment: You're unlikley to get the help you're after right now as you haven't actually asked a question. Try to narrow your question down to something specific that you have tried but hasn't worked, then we can help you solve it. You can always ask several questions, but right now this question is likely to be closed as lacking detail/focus. Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask